# Simple script works in terminal, but not crontab

Tags: server, scripts, cron

I'm doing an assignment for a university elective. I have to use a server from amazon ec2 and change its domain name, create a blog using apache and make a creative script that runs periodically using crontab.

Basically I just want my blog to have a night sky background when it reaches 8pm singapore time, and a day sky background when it reaches 6am.

I have a windows pc and my amazon server is using Ubuntu, so i'm using PuTTY and WinSCP to edit and stuff.

in `/var/www/html` there are two .txt files, one (day.txt) which says:

```
cp -R /var/www/html/downloads/Day/index.html /var/www/html
```

It replaces the index file located in `/html` with the one with a day picture background in the html. There is another file called night.txt which is the same except its `/Night/index.html` instead of `/Day/index.html`.

Let's say that the current `index.html` file in `/html` is the one with the day picture, and I use the putty terminal and run the night script with `./night.txt`, it works. When I refresh my website it changes to a day background, but when I try to do it with crontab it doesn't.

So I type `crontab -e` in the terminal,
and change the line to:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
18 14 *   *   *     /var/www/html/day.txt
```

I think this is meant to run at 2:18pm, but whenever I try to test with times it doesn't work.

I click ctrl o to save and ctrl x to exit, and i'm sure the crontab is there because when i look for it in WINSCP in `/tmp/crontab.7xxxx` it's there with the correct line.

i used `sudo chmod 700 night.txt` and `sudo chmod 700 day.txt` to give the script r/w/e permissions.

I am not sure what else I can include.
This a first semester course and we are encouraged to ask for help online, and I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: oh i have also tried using just /var/www/html/day in the crontab as well

Answer (score 0):

In order for that script to run it has to be in a .sh or shell file.
So you need to `cp day.txt day.sh`and then change your line in crontab to reflect this change and add the function to run the shell script. Make sure to include `#!/bin/bash` in your shell script.

```
18 14 * * * sh /var/www/html/day.sh
```

Comment: i turned them into .sh and then deleted the cp day.txt day.sh line, and my crontab is now


# m h  dom mon dow   command

 54 15 *   *   * sh  /var/www/html/night.sh and it still doesn't work.

Comment: also added #!/bin/bash on top of script

Answer (score 0):

i think, cron is a user of its own, and you deny it permission with 700. Try changing the group to cron, and giving it execution permission

```
chgrp cron /var/www/html/day.txt

chmod g+rx /var/www/html/day.txt
```

also, make sure you have the correct header in your script, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
```